# Properly handling data from mysqli prepared statements in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm not sure what could be going wrong with my code so I need some help. I followed the online tutorial the best I could with my data, but I couldn't do it exactly as they did it so I'll post a link to the tutorial page I am using.

The [tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) I am referring to uses a foreach loop with an array for their continents, but that sort of thing doesn't work with my data. So I used a for loop that will increment to 5, the LIMIT I used.

```
$start_from = 0; // arbitrary for this question
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT ID, name, image_path FROM people WHERE age=? LIMIT ? , 5")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $_GET['age'], $start_from);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    for($counter=0; $counter <=5; $counter++) /* "$counter <= 5" because my SQL query is limited to this number of items. */
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            foreach ($row as $r) {
                print_r("$r ");
            }
            print "\n";
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: `LIMIT ? , 5` never seen that before. Have you tried just `LIMIT 5` ?

Comment: what is the use of `counter` loop here ? I dont think it is necessary.

Comment: I could do that too Fred -ii-
the counter loop is similar to what was in the tutorial I think.

Comment: @eric - you say something is going wrong, but you don't say what. Are you getting an error message, or a white screen, or is it just not doing what it's supposed to?

Comment: I hope this is not another FILE 13 question Mr Fred. I really want to ask a good question and get some help.

Comment: @andrewsi The page doesn't change at all and the results I expect don't appear. Perhaps I need some error handling?

Comment: @eric - I'm not sure I know what you're saying; do you mean the LIMIT isn't working?

Comment: @andrewsi when I change the limit to what Fred suggested nothing changes. I suspect the issue may be with the mysqli_stmt_bind_param function.

Comment: @eric - what do you mean, nothing changes? I can't see what your code is doing, remember, so you're going to have to explain. If you leave the LIMIT out completely, it should return everything in the table; if you have `LIMIT 0,5` it should return the first five rows, I think. What is your code currently doing? What should it be doing? At the moment, the only explanation you've given is that nothing has changed.

Comment: No, it's not a `FILE 13` Eric. ;-) it's a good question, yet I for one am unable to resolve this.

Comment: I simply want to talk to my mysql server with php and print the data that I select.

Comment: Since you've setup your counter to go up to 5, why have the 5 in `LIMIT ? , 5` have you tried using `LIMIT ?`? I'm picking at straws here of course.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's for pages. it will $start_from the first number.

Comment: This may or may not work, however since `0` is the first iteration, and you're limited to `5`, then this `for($counter=0; $counter <=5; $counter++)` should probably be `for($counter=0; $counter <=4; $counter++)` Count these => `0` `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` = `6`

Comment: ah yes. off by one error.

Comment: Actually I might have made an error. I just edited my comment above from `for($counter=0; $counter <=6; $counter++)` to `for($counter=0; $counter <=4; $counter++)`

Comment: Did any of those solve your problem or there's no change?

Comment: ahhh. well, you see, I did just figure it out. it's kind of embarrassing, but I accidentally deleted my mysqli_connect because I had it included from a different file.

Comment: `Another Happy Ending` then.

Comment: However, my suggestion did kind of help, or did it not make a difference? Just curious, is all ;-)

Comment: I think the 4 will help if I'm starting at 0. :)

Comment: Yes, because `0` counts as `1` actually, being the first number (count) in the loop. I learned that lesson well (**the hard way**), many years ago.

Comment: @Fred, `LIMIT X, Y` does the same as `LIMIT Y OFFSET X`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fred already diagnosed the first problem in the comments, so I'll mark my answer CW.  That is, your for loop goes from 0 to 5, which actually runs for six iterations.

But that's not the only logic problem in your code. Consider this:

```
for($counter=0; $counter < 5; $counter++) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        ...
```

The `for` loop executes its block five times. But the internal block uses `while` to fetch *all* the rows in the result set on the first iteration of the `for` loop.

On the second through fifth iterations of the for loop, it tries to call `mysqli_fetch_array()` but once the query result has been read once, that function will return null for all subsequent times you call it.  So there's no use of the `for` loop at all.

In this case, there's not much harm done, because the `while` loop simply sees a null and terminates before it runs a single iteration. But this coding mistake may bite you in some future project.

Comment: Oh so it is just running the while loop multiple times I see.. that was unnecessary. I rewrote my code excluding the for loop completely.

Comment: I'm also using `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {` instead.

Comment: In retrospect, I could have asked these sorts of questions to have a better post: Do I need this `foreach()` or a `for()` loop in my code? and also, How can I do this with `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {` instead?

Comment: Yeah, as a tech writer friend of mine said, "you can't get the right answers until you ask the right questions."  :-)